# Converting parts of char array to Int array for calculations

Tags: c++, arrays, type-conversion

I have an array of structs which contains Formula Name, and Chemical Compound. I need to calculate atomic weight of compound.

```
   struct compounds{
        char name[20]; // Dihydrogen Monoxide (Water) 
        char formula[30]; //H2O
    };
```

---

```
const int SIZE = 100;
compounds collection[SIZE];
int formula_1[30];
int k;
```

---

I have trouble converting `collection.formula` to `int` values to do the actual weight calculations. I trying to use `isdigit()` to check for numbers in the formula and `atoi()` from `<studio.h>` to convert them to integers. My code is as follows:

```
for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
            infile >> collection[i].name >> collection[i].formula;
            //cout << collection[i].name << " " << collection[i].formula << endl;

            //Convertion CHAR to INT        
            for(int j=0; j<30; j++){
                if(isdigit(collection[i].formula[j])){
                    k = atoi (collection[i].formula[j]);
                }
            }
        }
```

---

```
//Store in array of INT
for (int m=0; m<30; m++){
    formula_1[m] = k;
}
```

---

What can be done to convert parts of `char` array containing numbers to convert them to `int`?

[The Weight Calculation of Water](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwZJq.jpg)

The error message is:

```
midterm_q2.cpp: In function 'int main()':
midterm_q2.cpp:40:39: error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
      k = atoi (collection[i].formula[j]);
                                       ^
In file included from midterm_q2.cpp:3:0:
c:\mingw\include\stdlib.h:335:38: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'int atoi(const char*)'
 _CRTIMP __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW  int atoi (const char *);
```

Comment: Atomic weight (could be a float number) or mass number (integer)? Whatever, computing both depends on elements! Extracting numbers from the formula won't give you anything interesting...or I missed some point?

Comment: I'm aware of that, the reason I'm trying to extract numbers from the formula is to know number of atoms of element in the compound. Such as water 2 atoms of Hydrogen & 1 atom Oxygen. => 2*Hydrogen_Weight + Oxygen_Weight

Comment: @YuryStanev, so you mean, you wish to extract `2` (for Hydrogen) and `1` (for Water) from H2O?

Comment: @abhishek_naik Yes that's exactly what I want.

Comment: @YuryStanev, in that case, you can just extract each character and test whether it is a number on not.  You while of course have to handle the case wherein the element appears without any suffix number (like just H2O instead of H2O1).

Comment: @abhishek_naik That's what I'm trying to do, but the atoi() doesn't seem to take a `char` as a parameter.

Comment: atoi takes char arrays not single chars. You could copy the digit chars to another string, add null terminator to it and convert that way (if you expect more than one digit at a time), otherwise you could just subtract value of '0' from the digit char and get numeric value that way.

Comment: @inkredibl I've done what you said `k = collection[i].formula[j] - 'o';`, but instead of printing 2 after `cout << k << " ";` it print -55 twice. I don't know what seems to be the cause. My full code can be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/QG6rUSDJ)

Comment: @YuryStanev read `atoi` manual! It takes a `char *` and convert the c-string to an int value. What you need is your own parsing. Substracting `0` must be done on digits only, but this is not a good solution either as their could be more than 9 atoms of a given element in a molecule. And elements sometime use two letters... No simple solution.